# Does anyone know the ST3 command for Key Bindings?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, keymapping

I've been playing with ST3 settings and key bindings but I've run into something strange.  I can't seem to be able to add a key binding to open the "Key bindings"

I want to add this shortcut (⌘+ctrl+,) to the Key Bindings menu option.

```
[
  { "keys": ["super+ctrl+,"], "command": "key_bindings"},
]
```

But this is not working.  Does anyone know the command that ST3 uses to open the "Default (OSX).sublime-keymap" files.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this is equivalent to clicking on: `Menu --> Preferences --> Key Bindings`.

```
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+,"], "command": "edit_settings", "args":
    {
        "base_file": "${packages}/Default/Default ($platform).sublime-keymap",
        "default": "[\n\t$0\n]\n"
    }
}
```

You can also open them using the Command Palette, under `Preferences: Key Bindings`.

Comment: Thank, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  I haven't tested it yet but I will soon.  Thanks a lot.  For future reference, where did you find that info?

Comment: I looked to see what command was specified in the `Default.sublime-commands` file under `Preferences: Key Bindings` and converted it into a key binding. I used the Package Resource Viewer plugin to open the `Default.sublime-commands` file (located in `Default` section).